# Bokeh hover info is behind some parts of the plot

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I have a complex code, but it basically work like this:
I have multiple functions, that creat parts of the plot depending on inputs.

The main part of the plot is always shown, and depending on user inputs I add different subplots.

```
main_plot = gener_main_plot()
plot = add_some_box1(main_plot)

if some_user_iput:
    plot = add_some_box2(plot)
    plot = add_some_box3(plot)
```

The plot is generated, however the hover boxes are acting strange. Lets say the function `add_some_box2` adds a hover to that part of the plot, but when I hover over that part, and if its big, it will be under the parts that were generated afterwards (`add_some_box3`).

Example:

[image]

How can I avoid this?

UPDATE: I am now using bokeh 1.0.1, however if I roll back to version 0.12.15, the problem is gone.